# Shader : What is mod2x Blending Mode

Tags: opengl, colors, directx, shader, blending

Everything is in the question. What is the Mod2x Blending Mode.
Is it ?

```
color1 * color2 * 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod2X aka Modulate2x is a common name for a blending configuration:

```
dst_color src_color
```

So because the blending equation is:

```
srcFactor * srcColor + dstFactor * dstColor
```

it results in the Mod2X being in fact just as you assumed:

```
2* sr_color * dst_color
```